# How to Create Mask for MaskedEditExtender for Special Characters?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

Suppose I want to allow the user to enter numbers, letters, and some special characters like *, $.

Plus limit to 3 characters.

How do I create a Mask for the AjaxControlToolKit MaskedEditExtender to allow only those characters?

I thought the mask would look something like:

"{9$\*\$}{9$\*\$}{9$\*\$}"

I started with this:

"{9$}{9$}{9$}"

I can't enter any characters into the TextBox.

According to one article the {} characters are "repetition delimiters".

So I thought using those parens was the correct syntax usage for setting the mask to allow a set of characters for a single character position in the textbox.

Thanks, Ed

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the FilteredTextBoxExtender.

Ed